# "a 100" vs "100"

Tags: grammar, numbers

This depends on context, but take the examples below. Which one is correct?

> She walked past the farm 100 times.

or

> She walked past the farm a 100 times.

The second seems wrong to me since separately "100" is pronounced "one hundred" but I have frequently seen this usage.

**Edit**

I changed the example to avoid some confusion surrounding my question.

Comment: Did the flow rate increase on one hundred occasions, or did it increase and is now on a level 100 times of that it was before?

Comment: @Helmar I suppose things were a bit ambiguous. I edited the question to make the example a bit clearer since the confusion was tangential to my question.

Comment: It's laziness in my opinion. If you want to use "a" then you should write out " hundred" to give "a hundred".  It's as awkward as someone writing "PIN number" when PIN means "Personal Identification Number". And it doesn't match. Would they write "two 100 times"?

Comment: “A 100” would be ‘a one hundred’… but more commonly (at least if you're talking about an increase of 10,000%, rather than a hundred individual increases of unspecified percentages) you would say _increased (a) hundredfold_ instead.

Comment: @Wudang _PIN_ does not really mean ‘personal identification number’ anymore. It originates as an abbreviation for that, but it no longer _means_ that in regular usage. We have non-numeric PIN codes, PIN numbers, taser guns, etc., all over the shop nowadays—even in dictionaries. That's just part of English, whether it originates in laziness (like most of language) or not.

Comment: I think they're both wrong.  If the flow increased from, eg 2 to 200, then I would say "The flow rate increased to 100 times its previous value".

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  - possibly but if so, would it still be written as an acronym? And I can't recall seeing non-numeric PIN codes. Those are passwords surely?  Though I do think "laziness" was a poor word choice on my part.

Comment: The flow rate increased by 100 *percent*.

Comment: @developerwjk That means something different. In any case, still tangential to my question so replacing it with "percent" would not change what I'm actually asking.

Answer (score 1):

> The flow rate increases 100-fold (one hundred-fold)

Would be a more idiomatic way of saying this, however, the questioner asks specifically about the original phrasing.

[image: Ngrams of different phrasings]

The above Ngram search would suggest that **a one hundred** has always been less frequently used in written language and as such should probably be avoided.

Your other suggestion of **by one hundred times** is definitely better than *a one hundred*.

However, standing out on the Ngrams (and that which sounds the best) is the phrase **by a hundred times**.

You may wonder why I have not included my own alternative answer of *hundred-fold* in the Ngram search; the below graph shows why. It turns out that *hundred-fold* is used so much more frequently, particularly a century ago, so as to block out any changes in usage of the other phrases. For this reason I would suggest that you use this phrasing. 
[image: Ngram with hundred-fold]

<sup>N.B.: because *hundred-fold* is a shorter phrase, its frequency readings are going to be higher than the other, longer, phrases.</sup>

Comment: I don't want to agree that it's more idiomatic, but the evidence seems compelling :) In any case, you're right that wasn't my original question anyway. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelMior I'm glad I could help, if your original question doesn't match what you meant then you should probably edit it.

Comment: I edited the example in the question which hopefully makes my point clearer (but unfortunately makes the answer make less sense.)

Comment: All your ngrams have only one hit?

Comment: @Helmar Rarer things like *by a 100 times* yes but most of them get lots of hits.

Comment: @MichaelMior Would you like me to change my answer in response to the new example?